# [Web API]Add Web App to WCF Service solution

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api

I have an issue related with WCF Service and Web API with below steps.

1. Create a WCF Service Application which is Service1.svc
2. Right Click this project, and Add -> Web API -> Web API Controller Class

Could I host Web API in WCF solution like this? I did not find any place to configure or register Web API, so if I run this project, Web API will not run correctly.
Code For hosting web api

```html
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080");

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
                new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

            using (HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
            {
                server.OpenAsync().Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Comment: why you want to do this ? i don't think you can combine web api and wcf easily in same project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't add a web API controller into a WCF service project and expect it to work. WCF and WebAPI have almost no overlap in terms of their dependency on the BCL.

I think Prashant, in his comment, puts it very eloquently when he argues:

> why you want to do this ?

You can host both a WebAPI *project* and a WCF service project in the same solution, but even though you can do this, why would you want to?

If you want to expose the same endpoints over both SOAP and REST you can already do this using only WCF.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just do not want to publish twice for wcf and web api. With wcf service, I could host it directly to IIS, and wei api support HttpSelfHost. I tried to add above code to Service1 class, and after I make a request to wcf, my web api will be host, and I could call it correctly. But, I have a little worry for this way, because, web api would not work until there is request to wcf service, and it seems every request will run above code. Could you share us if there is any method to run this code when I host my wcf service instead of use constructor?

Comment: @Edward I still don't understand why you would want to host both. Why do you think you need both?

Comment: I think there are valid cases where you would want to do this.  E.g. you have an existing WCF app and you want to add a Restful service accepting Json.  The WCF json serializer does not accept ISO dates, so you want the Newtonsoft one.  Swapping out the default JSON serializer is a lot of code in WCF, whereas adding the webapi controller is easy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204365/setting-up-web-api-within-wcf-project