# Can you add WCF Endpoint to .NET API

Tags: .net, api, wcf

Had a customer ask me this today.  Honestly it threw me, so I wanted to put it out there for someone who has had more coffee than I have today to answer.

They have an old .NET Website Project (WSP) which has WCF endpoints in it.  They also have a new "server" which is .NET API based.

Can we add WCF endpoints to the .NET API project?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English and limited knowledge. Do you mean that you want to invoke WCF service in the new web project which targets on another .net framework project

Comment: No worries Abraham and thanks for the question.  I was asking if anyone knows if it's possible to add a WCF endpoint to a .NET API project.  When we built the .NET API project we have only used RESTful routes.  I didn't know if it's possible to create a WCF endpoint inside of a .NET API project.  I didn't think so, but again....I couldn't find anything stating you couldn't either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution in this case is to create a proxy between the API and WSP like this:
`API -> WCF proxy -> WSP`.

WSP calls the proxy which in turns calls the API. The proxy wraps the API response into a WCF contract and passes it to WSP.

Comment: I was thinking something similar, but am I correct in stating a .NET API project cannot support a WCF endpoint?

Comment: You can, see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204365/setting-up-web-api-within-wcf-project

Comment: But still, I don't think you should. Splitting the projects is cleaner. What happens if in the future you want do deploy just the API project? If there is common logic between the projects, consider moving that to a library project.